Convert NBB XBRL into DataFrame
--Edit--
Added the missing namespace for open
Summary
The National Bank of Belgium (NBB) provides financial statements of public companies available to the public, via its API. Since 2022, these can be requested as JSON-files. Before only in XBRL.
This question is about XBRL.
Sources:

Webservices (API)
Taxonomy

As far as I understand, and maybe simplified, XBRL is regular XML file with the addition of being able to refer to a taxonomy, i.e. providing a "dictionary" for the attributes within elements to provide semantic meaning to the content encapsulated in the elements.
Example
<xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:afnp"><open:str>John</open:str></xbrldi:typedMember>

Given the namespaces are available, at one point or another, dim:afnp should point to a label first_name or equal.
I would like to be able to convert this XBRL data into a Pandas DataFrame (or .csv)
Reproduce the obstacle
Since an API key is necessary, I'll provide a piece of anonymised code that I believe should be sufficient. The taxonomy is available for download (.zip) in the second link I provided. It is simply a directory with organised folders that, similar to the namespaces, eventually leads to other xml/xld files.
Data from the API looks like this:
<xbrl 
xml:lang="nl"
 xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
 xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
 xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
 xmlns:dim="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/dict/dim"
 xmlns:open="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/dict/dom/open"
>
<!--More namespaces are given but I believe irrelevant here-->

<link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/fws/23.0/mod/m87/m87-f.xsd"/>

<!--The file repeats itself with <context> elements, just different id's.-->

<context id="c19">
<entity><identifier scheme="http://www.fgov.be">Some number</identifier></entity>
<period><instant>Some date</instant></period>
<scenario>
<xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:afnp"><open:str>John</open:str></xbrldi:typedMember>
<xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:annp"><open:str>Doe</open:str></xbrldi:typedMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:bas">bas:m31</xbrldi:explicitMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:ctc">ctc:m1</xbrldi:explicitMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:part">part:m2</xbrldi:explicitMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:psn">psn:m12</xbrldi:explicitMember>
</scenario>
</context>
</xbrl>"""

stringIO_xml = StringIO(xml)

What have I've tried?
I started with Arelle but, in my opinion, their documentation is not very helpful, at least not for a layman. I did not really get results and I felt the problem was providing the taxonomy as a local folder (and not HTTP-link). Also, their GUI would not accept the .zip file (it crashed). I have not tried the CLI.
I also read about Brel, which I believe is more focussed on EDGAR, from the U.S.A.
However, I feel it's more interesting to explore Pandas pd.read_xml() or lxml and work towards a customised script to decode the financial information.
I noticed pd.read_xml() offers the parameter namespaces which accepts a dict. Since the taxonomy is static, a conversion to a dictionary would only have to be done once.
I thought maybe providing a link to the local folder might help.
I have tried:
pd.read_xml(stringIO_xml, namespaces={'dim':'file:////Users/myname/Downloads/nbb-cbso-23.0.1/www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/dict/dim'})

Three /// for the file, one / as the start of my absolute path.
But get an error:
XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix open on str is not defined, line 16, column 51
If I read the error correct, that is about <open:str>John</open:str>, to which I do not even know how to counter that.
My questions
I will try to make it specific. Based on the information I've provided:

Is my logic flawed when I say that, if the taxonomy is provided even from a local folder, it would just be a matter of constructing my argument right in order to decode the information in the XBRL.
Is pd.read_xml() the right way to go or is it too limited for XBRL? I read that it might be too limited and lxml provides more options (despite lxml being the parser for pd.read_xml().

I am aware I should not ask broad, open questions so I'll ask more directly.

Is the following correct? To me, it seems, the logic of XBRL is rather simple: there is a taxonomy and there is a data file, and a parser needs to be able to interpret the data file, using the taxonomy.


That error is not due to you but the API response you posted which is missing the namespace xmlns URI for open. As a result, that markup is not well-formed XML. Are you sure you copied it correctly? If so, check with the vendor for sending such markup.

Well, working with these kind of files is certainly complex. As you say, it would be best to work with the lxml library which offers more versatility as compared to pandas.read_xml().

Addressing the error:


But get an error: XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix open on str is not
defined, line 16, column 51

Based on the minimal example from the data in the API and the namespaces you showed in your question, I would say that you are missing a namespace for the open:str tag. This should solve the first error you are encountering with your MRE:
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xml = """
<xbrl 
    xml:lang="nl" 
    xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" 
    xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" 
    xmlns:dim="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/dict/dim" 
    xmlns:open="http://www.example.com/open" ### Example of the missing part  
>
<link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/fws/23.0/mod/m87/m87-f.xsd"/>
<context id="c19">
<entity><identifier scheme="http://www.fgov.be">Some number</identifier></entity>
<period><instant>Some date</instant></period>
<scenario>
<xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:afnp"><open:str>John</open:str></xbrldi:typedMember>
<xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:annp"><open:str>Doe</open:str></xbrldi:typedMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:bas">bas:m31</xbrldi:explicitMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:ctc">ctc:m1</xbrldi:explicitMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:part">part:m2</xbrldi:explicitMember>
<xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:psn">psn:m12</xbrldi:explicitMember>
</scenario>
</context>
</xbrl>"""

stringIO_xml = StringIO(xml)
tree = etree.parse(stringIO_xml)
root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {
    'xbrl': 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance',
    'xbrldi': 'http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi',
    'dim': 'http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/dict/dim',
    'open': 'http://www.example.com/open' ### Example of the missing part
}

Then, to access the elements of the XPATH you need to work your way into the tree structure like so:
data = []
for context in root.findall('.//xbrl:context', namespaces):
    context_id = context.get('id')
    entity = context.find('.//xbrl:entity/xbrl:identifier', namespaces).text
    period = context.find('.//xbrl:period/xbrl:instant', namespaces).text
    scenario = context.find('.//xbrl:scenario', namespaces)
    
    row = {'context_id': context_id, 'entity': entity, 'period': period}
    
    for member in scenario.findall('.//xbrldi:typedMember', namespaces):
        dimension = member.get('dimension')
        value = member.find('.//open:str', namespaces).text
        row[dimension] = value
    
    for member in scenario.findall('.//xbrldi:explicitMember', namespaces):
        dimension = member.get('dimension')
        value = member.text
        row[dimension] = value
    
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

This will result in the following dataframe:

Again, I worked through the example you provided and not from the zipped files, which could lead to additional problems depending on how the XML structure is composed. However, I would say it should be pretty straightforward once you load the XML into a string.

For complex XML, consider XSLT, the special purpose language designed to transform XML files such as flattening the original version for data frame migration. Using the default lxml parser, pandas.read_xml() supports XSLT 1.0 transformations. With this approach, you only need a single line call of read_xml! Below breaks down the script sections to read XML and XSLT strings for the Pandas call.
Libraries
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


XML (added missing namespace definition, assuming omitted by OP)
xml = '''\
<xbrl xml:lang="nl"
    xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
    xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
    xmlns:dim="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/dict/dim"
    xmlns:open="example.org">

    <!--More namespaces are given but I believe irrelevant here-->
    <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/cbso/fws/23.0/mod/m87/m87-f.xsd"/>
    <!--The file repeats itself with <context> elements, just different id's.-->
    <context id="c19">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="http://www.fgov.be">Some number</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <instant>Some date</instant>
        </period>
        <scenario>
            <xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:afnp">
                <open:str>John</open:str>
            </xbrldi:typedMember>
            <xbrldi:typedMember dimension="dim:annp">
                <open:str>Doe</open:str>
            </xbrldi:typedMember>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:bas">bas:m31</xbrldi:explicitMember>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:ctc">ctc:m1</xbrldi:explicitMember>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:part">part:m2</xbrldi:explicitMember>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="dim:psn">psn:m12</xbrldi:explicitMember>
        </scenario>
    </context>
</xbrl>
'''


XSLT (special XML; retrieves descendants of <context> level)
xsl = '''\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:element name="data">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::doc:context"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="doc:context">
      <xsl:element name="context">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::doc:entity|descendant::doc:period"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::xbrldi:typedMember|descendant::xbrldi:explicitMember"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="doc:context/@*">
       <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="doc:entity|doc:period">
       <xsl:element name="{local-name(*)}">
         <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>  
    
    <xsl:template match="xbrldi:typedMember|xbrldi:explicitMember">
     <xsl:element name="{substring-after(@dimension, ':')}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
'''

Online Demo (click transform)

Pandas (single line call of read_xml)
with (StringIO(xml) as f, StringIO(xsl) as s):
    context_df = pd.read_xml(f, stylesheet = s)

print(context_df)
#     id   identifier    instant  afnp annp      bas     ctc     part      psn
# 0  c19  Some number  Some date  John  Doe  bas:m31  ctc:m1  part:m2  psn:m12


The Brel engine will support this out of the box in its next release.
